# Why I coudn't pass String[] to method that are waiting for vargargs

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have such problem: when I'm passing String[] to method that using String... I see error message like this

> The method changeFolderContent(String, FolderAction, String...) in the type Folder is not applicable for the arguments (String, FolderAction, String[])

```
@POST
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
void changeFolderContent(@PathParam(ID) String folderId,
                         @FormParam("action") FolderAction action,
                         @FormParam("item") String... item);


private void changeFolderContent() {
    folderClient.changeFolderContent(folderId, new FolderAction(), item);
}
```

Comment: Share your code, please.

Comment: Are you sure `FolderAction` is the same class in caller and callee?

Comment: and what is the type of `item`?

Comment: Please post a complete test program, including package declarations, includes, and the declarations of folderId and item.

Comment: Show the import statements of the class containing the method changeFolderContent(). Add `System.out.println(new FolderAction().getClass())`before calling that method, and show us the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be in the second argument, the only one that is not based on a java.lang class.

Here is an example of a very short test program:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("aa", 3, new String[]{"aa","bbb"});
  }

  private static void test(String s1, Integer i1, String... s2){
    for(String s : s2){
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

It compiles and runs, output:

```
aa
bbb
```

I suggest trying to strip the failing case down to something similar, removing everything that is not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: While informations here are certainly useful ["works for me" is not actually an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid). It just mean that OP didn't provide enough informations about his/her problem.

Comment: @Patricia Shanaha thank you for your comment about caller and callee. You were right partially. The problem was that there were class and enum with the same name. So I used class without thought that there can be such enum. So the problem was in the second parameter and not in third vargargs parameter

Comment: @Pshemo I agree with your comment. SE has a very unfortunate design error, coincidental coupling between the answer/comment distinction and format limitations. There is no official way to say something that is logically a comment, needs saying, and does not fit the comment format limitations.